# Rubymotion including a static library

Tags: rubymotion

I'm trying to add the a library to my Rubymotion project, it shows no errors but I can't seem to access the classes in the library, in my rakefile I have ...

```
app.vendor_project('vendor/iSpeechSDK', :static,
    :products => ["libiSpeechSDK.a"],
    :headers_dir => "Headers")

app.frameworks += ['iSpeechSDK']
```

The .a file and .h files in the Headers directory all exist

In my app_delegate I have this code ...

```
@sdk = iSpeechSDK.sharedSDK
```

But I get the error ...

Simulate ./build/iPhoneSimulator-5.0-Development/Mirror Mirror.app
(main)> 2012-07-19 10:50:05.978 Mirror Mirror[26195:11903] app_delegate.rb:13:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:': undefined local variable or method`iSpeechSDK' for # (NameError)
2012-07-19 10:50:05.980 Mirror Mirror[26195:11903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NameError', reason: 'app_delegate.rb:13:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:': undefined local variable or method`iSpeechSDK' for # (NameError)
'
*** First throw call stack:
(0xa88052 0x417d0a 0x207954 0x5c285 0x5bce1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from [Laurent on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/rubymotion/UGth3Ck81hw)

The problem is that the iSpeechSDK class name starts with a lower-case letter, which is not a valid constant name in Ruby.

In the next release you will be able to do ISpeechSDK.sharedSDK (as you can already do to access constants or enumerations that also start with a lower-case letter), but right now, a workaround can be:

```
NSClassFromString('iSpeechSDK').sharedSDK
```

Also, copy the .bundle file into the resources folder? The build system will not do it automatically (it will only link the app against the .a library)